# Bigtable-BigQuery Import via DataFlow: 2 questions on table partitioning and Timestamps

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

I have a job in Dataflow importing data from Bigtable into Bigquery by using built-in Dataflow APIs for both. I have two questions:

**Question 1:** If the source data is in one large table in Bigtable, how can I partition it into a set of sub- or smaller tables in BigQuery dynamically based on, say, the given Bigtable row-key known only at run-time?

The Java code in Dataflow looks like this:

```java
p.apply(Read.from(CloudBigtableIO.read(config)))
        .apply(ParDo.of(new SomeDoFNonBTSourceData()))
        .apply(BigQueryIO.Write
                  .to(PROJ_ID + ":" + BQ_DataSet + "." + BQ_TableName)
                  .withSchema(schema)
                  .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
                  .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));
        p.run();
```

So, since `BQ_TableName` has to be supplied at code-level, how can I provide it programmatically based on what is seen inside the `SomeDoFNonBTSourceData`, like a range of values of the current RowKey? If RowKey is 'a-c' then TableA, if 'd-f' then TableB, etc.

**Question 2:** What is the right way to export the Bigtable Timestamp into Bigquery so as to eventually reconstruct it in human-readable format in BigQuery?

The processElement function within the DoFn looks like this:

```java
public void processElement(ProcessContext c)
{
    String valA = new String(c.element().getColumnLatestCell(COL_FAM, COL_NAME).getValueArray());
    Long timeStamp = c.element().getColumnLatestCell(COL_FAM, COL_NAME).getTimestamp();

    tr.put("ColA", valA);
    tr.put("TimeStamp",timeStamp);
    c.output(tr);
}
```

And during the Pipeline construction, the BQ schema setup for the timeStamp column looks like this:

```java
List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("ColA").setType("STRING"));
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("TimeStamp").setType("TIMESTAMP"));
    schema = new TableSchema().setFields(fields);
```

So the Bigtable timestamp seems to be of type `Long`, and I have tried both `"TIMESTAMP"` and `"INTEGER"` types for the destination TimeStamp column in BQ (seems like there is no Long in BQ as such). Ultimately, I need to use the TimeStamp column in BQ both for 'order by' clauses and to display the information in human-readable form (date and time). The 'order by' part seems to work OK, but I have not managed to CAST the end result into anything meaningful -- either get cast errors or something still unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

Incidentally am here looking for an answer to an issue similar to Question 1 :).

For the second question, I think you first need to confirm that the Long timestamp is indeed a UNIX timestamp, I've always assumed BQ can ingest that as a timestamp without any conversion.

But you can try this...

```
Long longTimeStamp = 1408452095L;

Date timeStamp = new Date();
timeStamp.setTime(longTimeStamp * 1000);

tr.put("TimeStamp", timeStamp.toInstant().toString());
```

Comment: Sorry what type of Date is that in there? java.util.Date doesn't seem t have '.toInstant()' and Date from Google APIs doesn't have some of those other methods?

Comment: Could you try changing your language level to "8 - lambdas, type annotation etc". In Intellij go to project structure, select your module and change the language level. I don't know much on how to do this in Eclipse.

Comment: ah you are right -- i see its there in the docs. Must be something with my Eclipse. will figure it out. I will post here if I find something on Question 1...