# Streaming Dataflow pipeline with no sink

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We have a streaming Dataflow pipeline running on Google Cloud Dataflow
workers, which needs to read from a PubSub subscription, group
messages, and write them to BigQuery. The built-in BigQuery Sink does
not fit our needs as we need to target specific datasets and tables
for each group. As the custom sinks are not supported for streaming
pipelines, it seems like the only solution is to perform the insert
operations in a ParDo. Something like this:

[image]

Is there any known issue with not having a sink in a pipeline, or anything to be aware of when writing this kind of pipeline?

Comment: We have a pipeline that needs to write to different datasets/tables depending on the input. We use `side outputs` to write to N BigQuery sinks. Could this work for you too?

Comment: I thought about that, but how large is your N? For us N would be around 1 million.

Comment: Ehh...we have about 10-20 sinks. I think 1 million might be a problem! This sounds like an odd request - the fact that you need to write to a million different tables in BigQuery. Can you elaborate a little more on the problem you are trying to solve and give more context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should not be any issues for writing a pipeline without a sink. In fact, a sink is a type of `ParDo` in streaming.

I recommend that you use a custom `ParDo` and use the BigQuery API with your custom logic. Here is the definition of the [BigQuerySink](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L2947), you can use this code as a starting point.

You can define your own DoFn similar to [StreamingWriteFn](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L2611) to add your custom ParDo logic, which will write to the appropriate BigQuery dataset/table.

Note that this is using [Reshuffle](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L2991) instead of `GroupByKey`. I recommend that you use Reshuffle, which will also group by key, but avoid unnecessary windowing delays. In this case it means that the elements should be written out as soon as they come in, without extra buffering/delay. Additionally, this allows you to determine BQ table names at runtime.

Edit: I do not recommend using the built in BigQuerySink to write to different tables. This suggestion is to use the BigQuery API in your custom DoFn, rather than using the BigQuerySink

Comment: Would it be possible to post a few lines of code here to show how to do a custom ParDo to target a specific Dataset/Table within BIgQuery depending on the content of the ProcessContext inside the ParDo? We had a similar question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41698754/bigtable-bigquery-import-via-dataflow-2-questions-on-table-partitioning-and-tim ) on this, as we couldn't figure out how to pass the target BQ table name programmatically depending on the incoming PCollection element while using the built-in BQ DataFlow sink.

Comment: I do not recommend using the built in BigQuerySink to write to different tables. This suggestion is to use the BigQuery API in your custom DoFn, rather than using the BigQuerySink

@Thomas, 
I'm happy to follow help you work through any issues which you may run into as you write this code.

Would be willing to share some sample code once you get this working? If you decide to use an approach as I suggested. Again, please let me know if you run into any issues. I'm happy to help.

Comment: @AlexAmato - why not? If it's a reasonable number of sinks, then I do not see a problem with using multiple BigQuery sinks in the pipeline i.e. using side outputs. We do this on many of our pipelines and it works really well.

Comment: @GrahamPolley Yes, if the number of sinks is reasonable, then it should be okay. If there are too many then there are some memory issues. So its not recommended in general. Here is a bit more info. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues/62